# Rails has_many through query - find all excluding a subset

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Through a user, I want to be able to get all the companies NOT bookmarked by the user.

E.g. In companies {A, B, C, D, E, F}

If User-1 bookmarked {A, E}

I want to be able to query the user to get {B, C, D, F}

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bookmarks
    has_many :companies, :through => :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bookmarks
    has_many :users, :through => :bookmarks
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the logic down.  You simply need to implement it

Get the records of all companies

```
all_companies = Company.all
```

Get all companies for the user

```
user_companies = User.find(id).companies
```

and subtract the two arrays

```
not_user_companies = all_companies - user_companies
```

I just checked and you can subtract `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` from one another